# Install from pipfile using pipenv install gives error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pipenv

I have a project where I'm trying to install from the pipfile using pipenv install. I get som error when installing. Before i describe the error, this is what I did:

- Reinstall pipenv
- Reinstall Python (by also removing all leftover folders and everything in PATH etc.)
- Removing Python completely and then restarting computer and reinstalling again
- Tried with both 32-bit and 64-bit version of Python

This is how I do:

1. [Downloading](https://www.python.org/downloads/) latest Python executable for Windows
2. Installing the exec (tried both "quick install" and custom install for all users)
3. Running Windows PowerShell as Administrator, doing `pip install pipenv`
4. Going to my repository and running `pipenv install`

I also tried doing `pipenv install` inside `pipenv shell`. For all above I have the same error:

```
$ pipenv install
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (8d815b)…
An error occurred while installing click==7.0 --hash=sha256:2335065e6395b9e67ca716de5f7526736bfa6ceead690adf616d925bdc622b13 --hash=sha256:5b94b49521f6456670fdb30cd82a4eca9412788a93fa6dd6df72c94d5a8ff2d7! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing flask==1.0.3 --hash=sha256:ad7c6d841e64296b962296c2c2dabc6543752985727af86a975072dea984b6f3 --hash=sha256:e7d32475d1de5facaa55e3958bc4ec66d3762076b074296aa50ef8fdc5b9df61! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing flask-cors==3.0.8 --hash=sha256:72170423eb4612f0847318afff8c247b38bd516b7737adfc10d1c2cdbb382d16 --hash=sha256:f4d97201660e6bbcff2d89d082b5b6d31abee04b1b3003ee073a6fd25ad1d69a! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing flask-jwt==0.3.2 --hash=sha256:49c0672fbde0f1cd3374bd834918d28956e3c521c7e00089cdc5380d323bd0ad! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing flask-sqlalchemy==2.4.0 --hash=sha256:0c9609b0d72871c540a7945ea559c8fdf5455192d2db67219509aed680a3d45a --hash=sha256:8631bbea987bc3eb0f72b1f691d47bd37ceb795e73b59ab48586d76d75a7c605! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing itsdangerous==1.1.0 --hash=sha256:321b033d07f2a4136d3ec762eac9f16a10ccd60f53c0c91af90217ace7ba1f19 --hash=sha256:b12271b2047cb23eeb98c8b5622e2e5c5e9abd9784a153e9d8ef9cb4dd09d749! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing jinja2==2.10.1 --hash=sha256:065c4f02ebe7f7cf559e49ee5a95fb800a9e4528727aec6f24402a5374c65013 --hash=sha256:14dd6caf1527abb21f08f86c784eac40853ba93edb79552aa1e4b8aef1b61c7b! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing markupsafe==1.1.1 --hash=sha256:00bc623926325b26bb9605ae9eae8a215691f33cae5df11ca5424f06f2d1f473 --hash=sha256:09027a7803a62ca78792ad89403b1b7a73a01c8cb65909cd876f7fcebd79b161 --hash=sha256:09c4b7f37d6c648cb13f9230d847adf22f8171b1ccc4d5682398e77f40309235 --hash=sha256:1027c282dad077d0bae18be6794e6b6b8c91d58ed8a8d89a89d5
9693b9131db5 --hash=sha256:24982cc2533820871eba85ba648cd53d8623687ff11cbb805be4ff7b4c971aff --hash=sha256:29872e92839765e546828bb7754a68c418d927cd064fd4708fab9fe9c8bb116b --hash=sha256:43a55c2930bbc139570ac2452adf3d70cdbb3cfe5912c71cdce1c2c6bbd9c5d1 --hash=sha256:46c99d2de99945ec5cb54f23c8cd5689f6d7177305ebff350a58ce5f8de1669e --hash=sha256:500d4957e52dd
c3351cabf489e79c91c17f6e0899158447047588650b5e69183 --hash=sha256:535f6fc4d397c1563d08b88e485c3496cf5784e927af890fb3c3aac7f933ec66 --hash=sha256:62fe6c95e3ec8a7fad637b7f3d372c15ec1caa01ab47926cfdf7a75b40e0eac1 --hash=sha256:6dd73240d2af64df90aa7c4e7481e23825ea70af4b4922f8ede5b9e35f78a3b1 --hash=sha256:717ba8fe3ae9cc0006d7c451f0bb265ee07739daf76355d063661
54ee68d221e --hash=sha256:79855e1c5b8da654cf486b830bd42c06e8780cea587384cf6545b7d9ac013a0b --hash=sha256:7c1699dfe0cf8ff607dbdcc1e9b9af1755371f92a68f706051cc8c37d447c905 --hash=sha256:88e5fcfb52ee7b911e8bb6d6aa2fd21fbecc674eadd44118a9cc3863f938e735 --hash=sha256:8defac2f2ccd6805ebf65f5eeb132adcf2ab57aa11fdf4c0dd5169a004710e7d --hash=sha256:98c7086708b163
d425c67c7a91bad6e466bb99d797aa64f965e9d25c12111a5e --hash=sha256:9add70b36c5666a2ed02b43b335fe19002ee5235efd4b8a89bfcf9005bebac0d --hash=sha256:9bf40443012702a1d2070043cb6291650a0841ece432556f784f004937f0f32c --hash=sha256:ade5e387d2ad0d7ebf59146cc00c8044acbd863725f887353a10df825fc8ae21 --hash=sha256:b00c1de48212e4cc9603895652c5c410df699856a2853135b39675
91e4beebc2 --hash=sha256:b1282f8c00509d99fef04d8ba936b156d419be841854fe901d8ae224c59f0be5 --hash=sha256:b2051432115498d3562c084a49bba65d97cf251f5a331c64a12ee7e04dacc51b --hash=sha256:ba59edeaa2fc6114428f1637ffff42da1e311e29382d81b339c1817d37ec93c6 --hash=sha256:c8716a48d94b06bb3b2524c2b77e055fb313aeb4ea620c8dd03a105574ba704f --hash=sha256:cd5df7552386641
0809ca100dc9681e301e3c27567cf498077e8551b6d20e42f --hash=sha256:e249096428b3ae81b08327a63a485ad0878de3fb939049038579ac0ef61e17e7! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing marshmallow==3.0.0rc7 --hash=sha256:1ba81630e38a4c143faf54833357758d0b013ba8b0707b115f795153e970e5c4 --hash=sha256:f8dcb1f1fb9ebd26b2edc91878f32a229a3c079520611a21955bf9d73be2ab41! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pyjwt==1.4.2 --hash=sha256:87a831b7a3bfa8351511961469ed0462a769724d4da48a501cb8c96d1e17f570 --hash=sha256:99fe612dbe5f41e07124d9002c118c14f3ee703574ffa9779fee78135b8b94b6! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pymysql==0.9.3 --hash=sha256:3943fbbbc1e902f41daf7f9165519f140c4451c179380677e6a848587042561a --hash=sha256:d8c059dcd81dedb85a9f034d5e22dcb4442c0b201908bede99e306d65ea7c8e7! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing six==1.12.0 --hash=sha256:3350809f0555b11f552448330d0b52d5f24c91a322ea4a15ef22629740f3761c --hash=sha256:d16a0141ec1a18405cd4ce8b4613101da75da0e9a7aec5bdd4fa804d0e0eba73! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing sqlalchemy==1.3.4 --hash=sha256:c7fef198b43ef31dfd783d094fd5ee435ce8717592e6784c45ba337254998017! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing werkzeug==0.15.4 --hash=sha256:865856ebb55c4dcd0630cdd8f3331a1847a819dda7e8c750d3db6f2aa6c0209c --hash=sha256:a0b915f0815982fb2a09161cb8f31708052d0951c3ba433ccc5e1aa276507ca6! Will try again.
  ================================ 14/14 - 00:00:01
Installing initially failed dependencies…
     ================================ 14/14 - 00:00:02
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 254, in install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       editable_packages=state.installstate.editables,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1874, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       keep_outdated=keep_outdated
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1253, in do_init
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 862, in do_install_dependencies
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, False, failed_deps_queue, retry=False)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 681, in _cleanup_procs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: []
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Could not import runpy module', "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'runpy'"]
ERROR: ERROR: Package installation failed...
```

I have tried googling this but have not found any solution. Since I'm a beginner at pip and pipenv, I'm at a total loss in what to do. I also ran `python -m pipenv.help` so that I could provide that info:

```
$ python -m pipenv.help
<details><summary>$ pipenv --support</summary>

Pipenv version: `'2018.11.26'`

Pipenv location: `'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\pipenv'`

Python location: `'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\python.exe'`

Python installations found:

  - `3.7.3`: `C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe`

PEP 508 Information:


{'implementation_name': 'cpython',
 'implementation_version': '3.7.3',
 'os_name': 'nt',
 'platform_machine': 'AMD64',
 'platform_python_implementation': 'CPython',
 'platform_release': '10',
 'platform_system': 'Windows',
 'platform_version': '10.0.17134',
 'python_full_version': '3.7.3',
 'python_version': '3.7',
 'sys_platform': 'win32'}


System environment variables:

  - `ACLOCAL_PATH`
  - `ALLUSERSPROFILE`
  - `ANDROID_HOME`
  - `APPDATA`
  - `COMMONPROGRAMFILES`
  - `COMPUTERNAME`
  - `COMSPEC`
  - `CONFIG_SITE`
  - `CYGWIN_HOME`
  - `COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)`
  - `COMMONPROGRAMW6432`
  - `DISPLAY`
  - `DNX_HOME`
  - `DRIVERDATA`
  - `EXEPATH`
  - `GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE`
  - `GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE`
  - `GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES`
  - `GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM`
  - `GRADLE_HOME`
  - `GYP_MSVS_VERSION`
  - `HOME`
  - `HOMEDRIVE`
  - `HOMEPATH`
  - `HOSTNAME`
  - `INFOPATH`
  - `JAVA_HOME`
  - `LANG`
  - `LOCALAPPDATA`
  - `LOGONSERVER`
  - `MANPATH`
  - `MINGW_CHOST`
  - `MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX`
  - `MINGW_PREFIX`
  - `MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH`
  - `MSYSTEM`
  - `MSYSTEM_CARCH`
  - `MSYSTEM_CHOST`
  - `MSYSTEM_PREFIX`
  - `NODE_PATH`
  - `NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS`
  - `OLDPWD`
  - `ORIGINAL_PATH`
  - `ORIGINAL_TEMP`
  - `ORIGINAL_TMP`
  - `OS`
  - `ONEDRIVE`
  - `ONEDRIVECONSUMER`
  - `PATH`
  - `PATHEXT`
  - `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`
  - `PLINK_PROTOCOL`
  - `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`
  - `PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER`
  - `PROCESSOR_LEVEL`
  - `PROCESSOR_REVISION`
  - `PROGRAMFILES`
  - `PS1`
  - `PSMODULEPATH`
  - `PUBLIC`
  - `PWD`
  - `PROGRAMDATA`
  - `PROGRAMFILES(X86)`
  - `PROGRAMW6432`
  - `REACT_APP_TEST_VAR`
  - `REACT_APP_TEST_VAR_TWO`
  - `SESSIONNAME`
  - `SHELL`
  - `SHLVL`
  - `SSH_AGENT_PID`
  - `SSH_ASKPASS`
  - `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`
  - `SYSTEMDRIVE`
  - `SYSTEMROOT`
  - `TEMP`
  - `TERM`
  - `TERMINAL_EMULATOR`
  - `TMP`
  - `TMPDIR`
  - `USERDOMAIN`
  - `USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE`
  - `USERNAME`
  - `USERPROFILE`
  - `VS110COMNTOOLS`
  - `VS120COMNTOOLS`
  - `VS140COMNTOOLS`
  - `WINDIR`
  - `_`
  - `__INTELLIJ_COMMAND_HISTFILE__`
  - `PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK`
  - `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE`
  - `PIP_SHIMS_BASE_MODULE`
  - `PIP_PYTHON_PATH`
  - `PYTHONFINDER_IGNORE_UNSUPPORTED`

Pipenv–specific environment variables:


Debug–specific environment variables:

  - `PATH`: `C:\Users\mabj\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\mabj\bin;C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Python37;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\D
ocker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\B
luetooth Software;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.23;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Users\mabj\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\mabj\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\m
ysql5.7.14\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Gow\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Users\m
abj\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Program Files\HashiCorp\Vault;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\mabj\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\mabj\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\windows-build-tools\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\mabj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:
\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.5.9;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Users\mabj\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\mabj\AppData\
Local\Android\sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Gow\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel
\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Ruby24-x64\bin;C:\Users\mabj\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\mabj\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\mabj
\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl`
  - `SHELL`: `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe`
  - `LANG`: `sv_SE.UTF-8`
  - `PWD`: `C:/Users/mabj/Documents/repos/Philipsonska/philipsonska-api`


---------------------------

Contents of `Pipfile` ('C:\\Users\\mabj\\Documents\\repos\\Philipsonska\\philipsonska-api\\Pipfile'):

toml
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
flask-sqlalchemy = "*"
marshmallow = "*"
flask-cors = "*"
flask-jwt = "*"
pymysql = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"

[pipenv]
allow_prereleases = true




Contents of `Pipfile.lock` ('C:\\Users\\mabj\\Documents\\repos\\Philipsonska\\philipsonska-api\\Pipfile.lock'):

json
{
    "_meta": {
        "hash": {
            "sha256": "604f57d1e28a03d51d7def19bb003c466e6a9bdca8c852a20b83d6159c8d815b"
        },
        "pipfile-spec": 6,
        "requires": {
            "python_version": "3.7"
        },
        "sources": [
            {
                "name": "pypi",
                "url": "https://pypi.org/simple",
                "verify_ssl": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "default": {
        "click": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:2335065e6395b9e67ca716de5f7526736bfa6ceead690adf616d925bdc622b13",
                "sha256:5b94b49521f6456670fdb30cd82a4eca9412788a93fa6dd6df72c94d5a8ff2d7"
            ],
            "version": "==7.0"
        },
        "flask": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:ad7c6d841e64296b962296c2c2dabc6543752985727af86a975072dea984b6f3",
                "sha256:e7d32475d1de5facaa55e3958bc4ec66d3762076b074296aa50ef8fdc5b9df61"
            ],
            "version": "==1.0.3"
        },
        "flask-cors": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:72170423eb4612f0847318afff8c247b38bd516b7737adfc10d1c2cdbb382d16",
                "sha256:f4d97201660e6bbcff2d89d082b5b6d31abee04b1b3003ee073a6fd25ad1d69a"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==3.0.8"
        },
        "flask-jwt": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:49c0672fbde0f1cd3374bd834918d28956e3c521c7e00089cdc5380d323bd0ad"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==0.3.2"
        },
        "flask-sqlalchemy": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:0c9609b0d72871c540a7945ea559c8fdf5455192d2db67219509aed680a3d45a",
                "sha256:8631bbea987bc3eb0f72b1f691d47bd37ceb795e73b59ab48586d76d75a7c605"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==2.4.0"
        },
        "itsdangerous": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:321b033d07f2a4136d3ec762eac9f16a10ccd60f53c0c91af90217ace7ba1f19",
                "sha256:b12271b2047cb23eeb98c8b5622e2e5c5e9abd9784a153e9d8ef9cb4dd09d749"
            ],
            "version": "==1.1.0"
        },
        "jinja2": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:065c4f02ebe7f7cf559e49ee5a95fb800a9e4528727aec6f24402a5374c65013",
                "sha256:14dd6caf1527abb21f08f86c784eac40853ba93edb79552aa1e4b8aef1b61c7b"
            ],
            "version": "==2.10.1"
        },
        "markupsafe": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:00bc623926325b26bb9605ae9eae8a215691f33cae5df11ca5424f06f2d1f473",
                "sha256:09027a7803a62ca78792ad89403b1b7a73a01c8cb65909cd876f7fcebd79b161",
                "sha256:09c4b7f37d6c648cb13f9230d847adf22f8171b1ccc4d5682398e77f40309235",
                "sha256:1027c282dad077d0bae18be6794e6b6b8c91d58ed8a8d89a89d59693b9131db5",
                "sha256:24982cc2533820871eba85ba648cd53d8623687ff11cbb805be4ff7b4c971aff",
                "sha256:29872e92839765e546828bb7754a68c418d927cd064fd4708fab9fe9c8bb116b",
                "sha256:43a55c2930bbc139570ac2452adf3d70cdbb3cfe5912c71cdce1c2c6bbd9c5d1",
                "sha256:46c99d2de99945ec5cb54f23c8cd5689f6d7177305ebff350a58ce5f8de1669e",
                "sha256:500d4957e52ddc3351cabf489e79c91c17f6e0899158447047588650b5e69183",
                "sha256:535f6fc4d397c1563d08b88e485c3496cf5784e927af890fb3c3aac7f933ec66",
                "sha256:62fe6c95e3ec8a7fad637b7f3d372c15ec1caa01ab47926cfdf7a75b40e0eac1",
                "sha256:6dd73240d2af64df90aa7c4e7481e23825ea70af4b4922f8ede5b9e35f78a3b1",
                "sha256:717ba8fe3ae9cc0006d7c451f0bb265ee07739daf76355d06366154ee68d221e",
                "sha256:79855e1c5b8da654cf486b830bd42c06e8780cea587384cf6545b7d9ac013a0b",
                "sha256:7c1699dfe0cf8ff607dbdcc1e9b9af1755371f92a68f706051cc8c37d447c905",
                "sha256:88e5fcfb52ee7b911e8bb6d6aa2fd21fbecc674eadd44118a9cc3863f938e735",
                "sha256:8defac2f2ccd6805ebf65f5eeb132adcf2ab57aa11fdf4c0dd5169a004710e7d",
                "sha256:98c7086708b163d425c67c7a91bad6e466bb99d797aa64f965e9d25c12111a5e",
                "sha256:9add70b36c5666a2ed02b43b335fe19002ee5235efd4b8a89bfcf9005bebac0d",
                "sha256:9bf40443012702a1d2070043cb6291650a0841ece432556f784f004937f0f32c",
                "sha256:ade5e387d2ad0d7ebf59146cc00c8044acbd863725f887353a10df825fc8ae21",
                "sha256:b00c1de48212e4cc9603895652c5c410df699856a2853135b3967591e4beebc2",
                "sha256:b1282f8c00509d99fef04d8ba936b156d419be841854fe901d8ae224c59f0be5",
                "sha256:b2051432115498d3562c084a49bba65d97cf251f5a331c64a12ee7e04dacc51b",
                "sha256:ba59edeaa2fc6114428f1637ffff42da1e311e29382d81b339c1817d37ec93c6",
                "sha256:c8716a48d94b06bb3b2524c2b77e055fb313aeb4ea620c8dd03a105574ba704f",
                "sha256:cd5df75523866410809ca100dc9681e301e3c27567cf498077e8551b6d20e42f",
                "sha256:e249096428b3ae81b08327a63a485ad0878de3fb939049038579ac0ef61e17e7"
            ],
            "version": "==1.1.1"
        },
        "marshmallow": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:1ba81630e38a4c143faf54833357758d0b013ba8b0707b115f795153e970e5c4",
                "sha256:f8dcb1f1fb9ebd26b2edc91878f32a229a3c079520611a21955bf9d73be2ab41"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==3.0.0rc7"
        },
        "pyjwt": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:87a831b7a3bfa8351511961469ed0462a769724d4da48a501cb8c96d1e17f570",
                "sha256:99fe612dbe5f41e07124d9002c118c14f3ee703574ffa9779fee78135b8b94b6"
            ],
            "version": "==1.4.2"
        },
        "pymysql": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:3943fbbbc1e902f41daf7f9165519f140c4451c179380677e6a848587042561a",
                "sha256:d8c059dcd81dedb85a9f034d5e22dcb4442c0b201908bede99e306d65ea7c8e7"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==0.9.3"
        },
        "six": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:3350809f0555b11f552448330d0b52d5f24c91a322ea4a15ef22629740f3761c",
                "sha256:d16a0141ec1a18405cd4ce8b4613101da75da0e9a7aec5bdd4fa804d0e0eba73"
            ],
            "version": "==1.12.0"
        },
        "sqlalchemy": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:c7fef198b43ef31dfd783d094fd5ee435ce8717592e6784c45ba337254998017"
            ],
            "version": "==1.3.4"
        },
        "werkzeug": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:865856ebb55c4dcd0630cdd8f3331a1847a819dda7e8c750d3db6f2aa6c0209c",
                "sha256:a0b915f0815982fb2a09161cb8f31708052d0951c3ba433ccc5e1aa276507ca6"
            ],
            "version": "==0.15.4"
        }
    },
    "develop": {}
}


</details>
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this

Answer (score 0):

`runpy` is a module in Python 3's standard library. Maybe you should re-install your Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar (hash mismatch) and upgrading pip helped:
`pip install -r tools/requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Check `Pipenv` version: ensure that you are using a recent version of `Pipenv`. You can upgrade `Pipenv` using the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade pipenv
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered some situations where porting a Pipenv environment from another system (i.e. from a project working on a OS to another OS) fails because the hashes on Pipfile.lock are platform specific. In those cases, deleting the Pipfile.lock was the solution, as then pipenv is forced to search for the appropriate installation files for your system, instead of trying to reproduce exactly the previous installation.

Specially because the error messages show that Pipfile.lock hashes are being used in the installation attempts, the proposed solution should fit this case.